# question about css files for smartgwt project

Tags: css, gwt, fonts, stylesheet, smartgwt

I have what should be a simple problem, but so far I'm unable to come up with an answer. I would be very grateful if someone can humor me and just tell me where in the smartgwt jar I can find the stylesheets for changing the default look and feel of a smartgwt project.

I know how to inherit the supplied themes such as com.smartclient.theme.simplicity.Simplicity
but what I really need is to be able to modify simple things like global font size, style, color etc.

Please help...

Comment: Can you tell me which editor are you using for generating project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its located in war/[projectname]/skins/[skinName]/skin_styles.css in your apps war folder.

**EDIT**
In the Jar, its in

```
com/smartclient/theme/[themeName]/public/sc/skins/[themeName]
```