# how to use css to make smartgwt look like gwtext

Tags: java, css, gwt

I suppose the question most people would as is why would you want to do such a thing. The answer for me is I'm working in a large app that already has dozens of gwtext widgets. Since gwtext is extinct, it has been suggested additions to the app use smartgwt. I need a tabbed pane that contains editable listgrids to look like the equivalent in gwtext, for the sake of consistency in the add even though this will have it's own entry so there will be no mixing. I know how css is used with html. But I know nothing about javascript, that is the beauty of using gwt after all. How is css tied to js and is there an faily easy way to apply gwtext's css to a smartgwt widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply your custom CSS to SmartGWT. Depending on the skin you use for SmartGWT, it selects the CSS file and uses that to style the widgets. Look at this to see where the CSS files are located [question about css files for smartgwt project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091496/question-about-css-files-for-smartgwt-project/6094208#6094208).

You can get the style name associated with an element like the tabsets using `[Tabset].getStylePrimaryName()` and also apply a new style using `setStylePrimaryName()`.

I am not sure if GWText styles are similar to SmartGWT ones so you will have to check that out and make modifications if and when needed.

Wont be an easy task to make it look like GWText unless the skin style sheets are similar, but at least there are ways to do it.