# Where are the CSS files stored in smartgwt?

Tags: css, smartgwt

I started messing with SmartGWT the other day, but ive stumbled in this ridiculous spot..
This is a question that the documentation should respond, but i havent found any simple and straightforward solution.
What i want:
add 5px to the left margin of a Hlayout.
I tried the method setMargin(), but it applies margins to the 4 margins. Since i just want the left one, i was left with the option to use the this.setStyleName(), which leads me to the problem.

How should i go about it? is there a master css file that i have to edit? should i create a custom css file and put there my customizations? where should it be saved?

I tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091496/question-about-css-files-for-smartgwt-project/), but it doesnt seem to work for me. am using smartgwt v.2.5

Answer (score 1):

There are no special restrictions with CSS and SmartGWT.  You can put an inline <style> in your host .html, link a stylesheet from there, etc.

There is also no need to modify a skin in order to add or customize styles, but if you do want to create a custom skin, see the instructions in the QuickStart Guide, Extending SmartGWT chapter.

Finally you don't need CSS to do this anyway since there is a dedicated Layout.setLayoutLeftMargin() for setting the left margin.